# Google maps "For developement purposes only"

Tags: javascript

My google map is not showing correctly. It shows "for development purposes only" and google says I need to create and enable a billing account and create an API key. I have done this but do I need to change or add something in the code?

```html
 // Get the HTML DOM element that will contain your map
 // We are using a div with id="map" seen below in the <body>
 var mapElement = document.getElementById('map');

 var map = new google.maps.Map(mapElement, mapOptions);
 var image = 'http://filmservice.no/wp-content/themes/filmservice16/img/ikon/map-marker.png';
 var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: new google.maps.LatLng(59.969826, 10.905725),
  animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
  map: map,
  icon: image,
  title: 'Filmservice AS'
 });
 
function toggleBounce() {
  if (marker.getAnimation() !== null) {
    marker.setAnimation(null);
  } else {
    marker.setAnimation(google.maps.Animation.BOUNCE);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The change you'll need to make is actually in your HTML markup, where you include the google maps API script:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```

See the tutorial at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial for more information.

Comment: Yes of course. Just the markup... Haha, the simpler the better :-)